# Will the static_cast will run every time in the for loop condition?

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I have a code segment like below

```
int name = 10;

for( size_t var = 0; var < static_cast<size_t>( name ); var++ )
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

In the above code every time the condition in `for` loop is checked, will the casting will also happen that many number of times. I was thinking that there could be some compile time optimization for the same. I am using MS VS 2010.

Note: The value name can be statically initialized or can be evaluated on run time.

Comment: What's wrong with making `name` a `size_t`, anyway?

Comment: This case is unlikely to cause a performance problem.

Comment: lets say I am using an API which accepts `name` as `int` only and then I consume the same in `for` loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Or making `var` an `int`?

Comment: @NeilKirk I want to know whether is this only a one time activity.

Comment: You should rather ask: is this an *activity* at all? And the answer is: check the generated code...

Comment: We can't really answer that, since it's about whether (and how) the compiler optimises it. Peek at the assembly if you want to know for your particular setup.

Comment: Like most everything else, *it depends*. In your case the casting is very simple (converting from one integer type to another) and so it will by compile-time only, there are cases where casting might involve run-time code. Now for the question about if that part of the condition will be run every loop iteration, it *also* depends. In your simple case there is nothing to do besides the comparison so no extra code is generated, other cases the compiler may optimize it, or it may not.

Comment: The middle condition is evaluated every iteration, so if the cast requires run-time behaviour (int and size_t may be different sizes), it may occur more than once.

Comment: I know I could have either opted only for `int` or `size_t` but I am working on a legacy code and that's the it is expected in production.

Comment: A little snippet to test runtime execution off the middle condition: `size_t bar=10;for(size_t foo=0;foo<bar--;bar--){std::cout<<foo<<" "<<bar<<std::endl;}` bar will be decremented 2 times each but the first step.

Comment: You can make sure that such things are only executed once (and thereby also document it implicitly, which is also valuable) by creating the variable in the loop header: `for (size_t i=0, count=static_cast<size_t>(name); i!=count; ++i) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an optimisation-free environment, the `static_cast` would indeed be evaluated in each iteration of the loop.

It is quite possible that the compiler will optimise it out of the loop, *if* it can prove that the value of `name` doesn't change between iterations. To be sure of that, inspect the generated assembly.

Note that depending on your platform, it's possible the cast is a no-op. If `int` and `size_t` are of the same size (common on 32-bit platforms), the cast has no runtime cost associated with it. If their sizes differ (common on 64-bit platforms), there can be a runtime operation involved. Again, to know for sure, check the assembly.

Comment: sorry but what is no-op, is it no operation

Comment: @Surfing_SO Yes, no operation.

Comment: it would be really helpful if someone can help on what happens on popular compilers like `gcc` and `VS`

Comment: @Surfing_SO There's no way to do that, I am afraid - it depends on the body of the loop and whether the compiler can prove that the body does not modify `name`.